# Using react native video with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use react-native-video module, with expo,
I installed as follows:

```
-yarn add react-native-video

-react-native link react-native-video
```

here gives me a warning:

```
(node:504) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

then my code would be:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';

<View>
            
    <Video source={{uri: 'https://www.Stream.com/StreamUrl/ny/hls'}}
                ref={(ref) => {
                  this.player = ref
                }}                                      // Store reference
                onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
                onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
                style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
    
              </View>
```

when executing it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
'RCTVideoInstance.Constants')
```

[image]